# Why does gedit print cover pages?

Tags: 11.04, gedit

I am printing a program listing from Gedit ok but am also getting a Cups cover page before and after the listing. An annoying waste of paper etc.

I have just started using Ubuntu, so this may have nothing to do with the version.
Can someone help me?

- I have checked `system-config-printer` and made sure "starting banner" is set to None
- I have reloaded the drivers and the cover pages are gone. However, the filename and first line of code are now omitted from the print-out. If I create a pdf file, all details are there. Short of buying a new printer, is there anything I can do ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned as there hasn't been any activity for a longer period of time. I'm voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the printer configuration.

In the printer configuration (launch from command line as `system-config-printer`), right click on the printer, choose *Properties*, the in the *Policies* tab look for *Starting Banner*.

[image]